# How to show tool tip on click on static control and hide tool tip when clicked elsewhere using specifically win32 c++ api

Tags: c++, winapi, tooltip

I know how to normally make tool tip. But the problem is tool tip appears when mouse pointer is over control. I want tool tip to appear when static control is clicked.

I want to show tool tip only when user clicks the static control and hide the tool tip if user clicks outside the control. What messages should be handled and how to proceed? Any help will be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I need not create or destroy child window. I handled WM_LBUTTONDOWN message to hide the tool tip. It can be implemented as given at the following link. [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh298405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh298405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)